# Validation of numerical values when updating record in Rails 5 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing a Rails 5 API where I have a Company model.

Company has 3 fields, name, email and markup.

And a validation

```
validates :name, presence: true
validates :email, presence: true
validates :markup, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

When I want to update the record using PUT: company/1 I only want to pass along the values that changed. So if I don't send a name parameter then the name does not change. That works and the validator does not complain.

Only the markup validation causes troubles. If I don't pass a long a markup parameter in the request I get an error that markup must be an integer.

How do I have to change my validation so that markup is required, but I update a record do not have to pass it along if it did not change?

In my CompanyController I have

```
def update
    if @company.update(company_params)
      render json: {
        status: 200,
        message: 'Company updated successfully',
        company: @company
      }.to_json()
    else
      render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end
```

And this:

```
def company_params
      params.permit(:name, :email, :markup)
end
```

Comment: can you show your controller code?

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to update an 'old' record that does not have the `markup` attribute set? And what is the database column type of `markup`? Integer, or... string?

Answer (score 0):

**Suppose Todo Model has three fields :**

tilte,
created_by,
count

**In Model**

```
class Todo < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :items, dependent: :destroy

  # validations
  validates_presence_of :title, :created_by
  validates :count, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
end
```

**In Controller**

```
    def update
      if @todo.update(todo_params)
        render json: {
           status: 200,
           message: 'todo updated successfully',
           todo: @todo
          }.to_json()
      else
        render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
       end
    end
```

**Curl Request**

```
curl -H "Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJleHAiOjE0ODc0MjI5MDN9.QeNmnxcrxZtb_Yy68aQ5jmV6r2qTTLkJS2NdyEeEpfc" http://localhost:3000/todos/1 -XPUT -d"title=nothing&created_by=rbk"
```

Here i dont pass count field in curl request still it give 200 response

**Ouput**

```
{"status":200,"message":"todo updated successfully","todo":{"id":1,"title":"nothing","created_by":"rbk","count":123,"created_at":"2017-02-17T13:06:24.188Z","updated_at":"2017-02-17T13:13:01.109Z"}}
```

I m able to get response i think you should check your curl request